# Simplify R code for computing group statistics across multiple factors

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, factors

I am trying to compute the variance for each group in a data set with multiple factors. For example, the data set below is the first 6 lines of a data frame with 5 columns: 4 factors of two levels each (No and Yes) and 1 continuous variable:

| Factor A | Factor B | Factor C | Factor D | VarX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | No | 66.8 |
| No | Yes | Yes | No | 66.0 |
| Yes | No | No | No | 58.4 |
| No | Yes | Yes | Yes | 68.3 |
| Yes | Yes | Yes | No | 61.8 |
| Yes | No | No | No | 67.3 |

What I want to do is produce a summary table such as the one below:

| Factor | SD (NO) | SD (YES) | SD Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Factor A | 3.79 | 3.51 | 1.08 |
| Factor B | 3.44 | 3.83 | 1.11 |
| Factor C | 3.77 | 3.53 | 1.07 |
| Factor D | 3.92 | 3.32 | 1.18 |

For each factor, I have calculated the standard deviation at each level ("No" and "Yes") as well as the ratio of the two standard deviations.

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
#
# Define modify function for SD ratio column
#
sd_ratio<-function(x,y){
  return(max(x,y)/min(x,y))
}
#
# Set up storage
#
nc<-4 # number of factors in data
testDataSum<-tibble(SD_No=rep(NA,nc),
                   SD_Yes=rep(NA,nc),
                   SD_Ratio=rep(NA,nc))
#
Factor<-vector("list",4)
SDList<-vector("list",4)
#
# For Loop. Group data by factors 1,2,3,4
#
for (i in 1:4){
  Factor[[i]]<-names(testData[,i])
  SDList[[i]]<-testData %>% 
  group_by(testData[,i])%>%
  summarize(SD=sd(VarX))
}
# Load summary DF with data by unlisting SDList
#
testDataSum$SD_No<-as.vector(matrix(unlist(SDList),ncol=4,byrow=T)[,3])
testDataSum$SD_Yes<-as.vector(matrix(unlist(SDList),ncol=4,byrow=T)[,4])
testDataSum$SD_Ratio=modify2(testDataSum$SD_No,testDataSum$SD_Yes,sd_ratio)
#
# Load formatted factor names and put it at the front
#
testDataSum<-testDataSum %>% 
  mutate(Factor=unlist(Factor)) %>%
  relocate(Factor)
# Show results
testDataSum
```

My request is for help in simplifying this code. This works but it seems horribly ugly and complex, not to mention difficult to come back to at a later date and modify. I believe there is a much simpler way to do it without a for-loop, and without the ungainly process of unlisting SDList using the **"as.vector (matrix (..."** lines. I have reviewed the documentation for DPLYR and PLYR, especially the grouping section, but I am baffled. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Here is a link to a github repository with the code and a csv file with 192 rows that you can use to produce the result table.

[Git Hub Link for code and Data](https://github.com/pmgarafola/StackOverflowRQuestionDec2021.git)

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `reshape2`, `dplyr`, and `tidyr`

When I read your data, column names get broken, so I rename them beforehand.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(reshape2)

names(df) <- c("A","B","C","D","VarX")


df %>%
  melt(id.vars = "VarX", variable.name = "Factor") %>%
  group_by(Factor, value) %>%
  summarize(sd = sd(VarX)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Factor, values_from = sd, names_from = value, names_glue = "sd_{value}") %>%
  mutate(SD_ratio = pmax(sd_No,sd_Yes)/pmin(sd_No,sd_Yes))

  Factor sd_No sd_Yes SD_ratio
  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
1 A       3.51   3.79     1.08
2 B       3.83   3.44     1.11
3 C       3.53   3.77     1.07
4 D       3.92   3.32     1.18
```

Comment: This is certainly cleaner and more concise. I will have to study it to understand everything you've done  Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Here is another way to do it using pivot_longer instead of melt:

Comment: `names(df) <- c("A","B","C","D","VarX")
df<-df%>%
  pivot_longer(c(1:4),names_to="Factor",values_to="value")%>%
  group_by(Factor,value)%>%
summarize(sd=sd(VarX))%>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Factor, values_from = sd, names_from = value, names_glue = "sd_{value}")%>% 
  mutate(SD_ratio = pmax(sd_No,sd_Yes)/pmin(sd_No,sd_Yes))
df`

Comment: @PeterG This is also nice way :D.